# Angular-material - FAB Speed Dial does not work with Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-material, long-running-processes

I'm developing an Ionic application and I'm having some issues to make  [FAB Speed Dial](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/fabSpeedDial) works properly. This component is located at an specific page, and the user should navigate through 2 pages before open the page mentioned. When the page is loaded, the Fab Speed Dial is opened and nothing happens when I click. If I refresh only this page (using ionic serve), the component works normally:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <div>
        <md-fab-speed-dial md-open="fab.isOpen" md-direction="down" class="md-fling">
            <md-fab-trigger>
                <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab bk-marrom1">
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icon-more-horiz.svg" style="width:30px; height:30px"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </md-fab-trigger>
            <md-fab-actions>
                <md-button aria-label="Telefonar" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini bk-marrom2">
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icon-phone.svg" aria-label="Telefonar"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button aria-label="E-mail" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini bk-laranja-light">
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icon-mail-outline.svg" aria-label="E-mail"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button aria-label="Compartilhar" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini bk-marromsub">
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icon-share.svg" aria-label="Compartilhar"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </md-fab-actions>
        </md-fab-speed-dial>
    </div>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

I've got no exceptions in console, only this warning:

> Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343.

And is not in my code, but in FAB Speed Dial code:

```
compile: function(element, attributes) {
    var children = element.children(); -> this is the line with long-running timer task
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is an open bug with chrome for WebView and mobile: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=574343. You can track the progress on this bug for your issue